# Trigger beforeunload for an iframe inside a modal

Tags: html, razor, iframe

I am trying to trigger the prompt "You are leaving unsaved changes" when a user trys to close the modal without saving their changes they have made in the iframe. The application has an Iframe inside a modal, and all the changes the user will make are on the Iframe, the modal has the "X"/Close button. How can I communicate between my iframe and modal to trigger the preventNaigation?

I have tried adding a EventListener('beforeunload') to the iframe but since frame is in a modal and modals are only able to be hidden instead of closed, this event will not be triggered when the modal is closed only when: a new modal is opened, or when the user closes the tab/window.

I have also tried to put a change method in my iframe
`$(#form0 :input").change(function () { preventNaviagation(); });`

and in my modal
`function preventNaigation() { window.beforeunload = function (e) { return "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page? Any unsaved changes will be lost."; } }`

I have also tried to hit the method by using document.getElementId("iframe") but still have not been able to get the preventNaviagtion to be triggered.